# Shed foundation across concrete and dirt, what approach would be good to use

Tags: foundation, shed

I am planning on building a small shed, perhaps 8 or 10 foot by 4 foot.  The place I want to build the shed will span across concrete and dirt/ground.  The ground is about 2 foot, so it would be half of the 4 foot dimension.

After looking at YouTube video, I was thinking of using a few Pier Blocks on the ground part, but not sure what to use on the concrete.  What would be a good consideration for this type of foundation layout?  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer; let's see if one of our  experts can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.